# Using Ajax variable outside of function

Tags: javascript, ajax, global-variables

I got below code and I want to use ajax response out side of function but it continuously shows me undefined, I know it is easy but how to handle it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
<script>
 var sourceData;
 var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      sourceData = this.responseText;

     //
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:34560/test/js/source.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=sourceData;
</script>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="test"></div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Update:

I do not want to use ajax inside function as you can see it is inside script tag.

Comment: it is using ajax in the function, i do not want to use it inside function
as you can see it is inside script tag

Comment: also it is ajax and this is javascript, and i did it before not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into the problem of understanding asynchronous javascript.
Basically, when you call `xhttp.send()`, javascript sends the request, but the code is not paused. The next line (where you try to use `sourceData`) is called, and the server has not yet responded to you `send()` request, so your `onreadystatechange` function has not been called yet, and `sourceData` is indeed `undefined`.
If you want to do anything after the server answers to your asynchronous request, you need to put it inside the `onreadystatechange` function :

```
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a synchronous call rather than async one.

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

Note however that this blocks the script and makes your web page unresponsive until the server reply has arrived. You should learn about asynchronous callbacks instead.